# Is it possible to create an array of strings, if so, why am I getting this error: error: expected expression?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, typedef

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
typedef array<string,3> TString;

int main(){
    TString str;
    str = {"Hi","Example", "Error"};
    cout << str[0] <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The original error code I get:

> **pruebastr.cpp:10:8: error: expected expression
>           str = {"Hi","Example", "Error"};
>                 ^ 1 error generated.**

Am I defining the array the wrong way or initializing it badly?

Comment: Try `TString str {"Hi","Example", "Error"};` instead.

Comment: works fine with `std=c++11` flag.

Comment: "...or initializing it badly". Your `=` line is not *initialization*, but *assignment*. However, it should compile in C++11.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that your compiler standard flag(std) is set to at least c++11

Answer (score 1):

What compiler are you using?

clang 3.9.0 -std=c++11: https://godbolt.org/g/31aYx7

gcc6: https://godbolt.org/g/0j52Zy

both compiles and works fine, with same output: "Hi"